# JaxaFX Shader Issue on Ubuntu: Help translate error

Tags: java, opengl, javafx, shader, esri

An error is being reported in Java that I would like to resolve. I'm not sure what is causing the error, and I would like to understand the cause.

I'm using JavaFX, Java 8 and Ubuntu OS. I'm attempting to use the getting stated guide here: https://developers.arcgis.com/java/latest/guide/display-a-scene.htm

Unfortunately, I'm getting a error that I cannot understand.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException:Error code: 18
Error message: Internal error exception
Additional error message: star_draw,GL_VERTEX_SHADER:0:3(10): error: GLSL 1.50 is not supported. Supported versions are: 1.10, 1.20, 1.30, 1.00 ES, 3.00 ES, 3.10 ES, and 3.20 ES
```

How can I understand this error and where the problem lies so I can start troubleshooting a solution?

```
at com.esri.arcgisruntime.internal.mapping.view.RenderingContext.nativeDrawMap(Native Method)
```

Here is my glxinfo:

```
mark@marks-computer:~$ glxinfo | grep version

server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
    Max core profile version: 4.5
    Max compat profile version: 3.0
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 17.4.0-devel
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 17.4.0-devel
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 17.4.0-devel
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
```

The last line seems to indicate I should be ok?

Comment: Perhaps you should do as the error says and use a supported version of GLSL

Comment: What version of mesa do you have installed?

Comment: @JacobB. When running glxinfo, it seems that I have 3.20 ES

Comment: @sillyfly, seems to be 17.4.0-devel

Comment: Perhaps someone can explain to me why its trying to use GLSL 1.5.0?

Comment: Do you have access to the shader source? I didn't see any in your link, but it's possible the shader has a `#version 150` directive which would attempt to use GLSL 1.5.

Comment: Please post code for shader Cormac is right there must be #version directive used in shader. Remember that version is not of opengl but of GLSL.

Comment: Yes it looks like the library developers have upgraded the hardware minimum GLSL spec without changing what's posted on the dev web site. "Linux applications require support for OpenGL 3.0 and Shader Language 1.3 minimum."  The error message is effectively saying those should be 3.2 and 1.5 respectively.  If you're really lucky, updating graphics card driver/firmware might fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue with **Ubuntu 14.04**. I've added several methods to try:

The line in your ***glxinfo*** seems to solve everything:

> OpenGL shading language version string: **1.30**

Your OpenGL driver only supports GLSL version **1.30**.

- Try adding **#version 330** (or any other version) in your shader code.
- Or try forcing **MESA_GLSL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=1.50**
- `--use-gl=egl` might work as a temporary solution.

Try all of them, and if *none* of them works successfully, **try contacting the devs.**

Answer (score 0):

Your application is trying to compile a GLSL 1.50 shader. GLSL version 1.50 was introduced with OpenGL 3.2, so trying this on an OpenGL context with a version below GL 3.2 is not guaranteed (and generally quite unlikely) to work. The error message you got explicitly tells you that GLSL 1.50 is not available.

Since you use Linux with the Open Source drivers from the [Mesa 3D project](https://www.mesa3d.org/), there is not much you can do here. Mesa only implements the *core profile* of modern OpenGL, not the compatibility profile. For legacy applications, mesa also supports legacy contexts up to GL 3.0 (GLSL 1.30). And from the output it is very clear that your application does use a legacy context.

Note that the OpenGL specification explicitly states that compatibility profile support is *optional*. Your application simply tries to use GL 3.2+ features on a legacy context, which *is just broken*, as per the spec. This will only work on drivers exposing the optional *compatibility profile*. The only true solution would be to fix JavaFX to either use a core profile context (which requires getting rid of all deprecated GL features they are usings - and that stuff is now deprecated since *a decade*!), or to limit itself to GL 2.1 and keep a legacy context (on linux with mesa, 3.0 would work too, but OSX on mac can do at most 2.1 in legacy mode).

You *might* be able to work around your issue by setting the environment variable `MESA_GLSL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=150` to fake support for GLSL 1.50 in your 3.0 context, but that is only a poor hack which could introduce all kinds of issues on it's own...

Comment: I've awarded the bounty to this answer as it's the most comprehensive answer and the bounty was expiring. Seems the answer is unfortunately, "nothing can be done". The only other option I can think of is to try and force my Optimus laptop to use the GeForce driver instead of the Intel? Any ideas if this is possible? Also, is it the hardware or driver that dictates the maximum OpenGL version?

Comment: Well, your hardware is capable of GL 4.5, as mesa demonstrates (there might be a few features which mesa might have to emulate to reach that level, notably 64 bit float support on older intel GPUs), so in principle, one could write a GL 4.5 compatibility driver for it. The mesa devs just decided against putting so much effort into supporting outdated features. The nvidia proprietary driver on the other hand doues support compatibility profile, you actually should be able to run this with the nvidia card if you get optimus or PRIME to work.